# Pandas converting SOME bool to int and also not dropping correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Yes, still fighting this but it's gotten a bit clearer and complex at the same time.  We are trying to remove duplicates but also break into subsets. I'm still getting a lot of dupes but I've noticed part of that may because SOME of the boolean values in the 'Fixable' column are being translated to Int, but not all.

Given the following:

Data for one Month:

```
Cluster,Namespace,Deployment,Image,Component,CVE,Fixable,Component Upgrade,Severity,Discovered At,Reference
com,calico-system,calico-node,mcr.microsoft.com/oss/calico/node:v3.24.6,bash,CVE-2022-3715,false,,MODERATE,"September 06, 2023",https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-3715
com,calico-system,calico-node,mcr.microsoft.com/oss/calico/node:v3.24.6,elfutils-libelf,CVE-2021-33294,false,,LOW,"September 06, 2023",https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2021-33294
com,calico-system,calico-node,mcr.microsoft.com/oss/calico/node:v3.24.6,glibc,CVE-2023-4527,false,,MODERATE,"September 12, 2023",https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2023-4527
com,calico-system,calico-node,mcr.microsoft.com/oss/calico/node:v3.24.6,glibc,CVE-2023-4806,false,,MODERATE,"September 12, 2023",https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2023-4806
com,calico-system,calico-node,mcr.microsoft.com/oss/calico/node:v3.24.6,glibc,CVE-2023-4813,false,,MODERATE,"September 12, 2023",https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2023-4813
```

and the Second month has some duplicates.  And the relevant code:

```
  COMPARE_SUBSET_ALL_UNIQUE=["Cluster", "Namespace", "Deployment", "Component", "CVE", "Fixable", "Severity"]

  #################################
  #  Add the Month to the columns #
  #################################
  dataframe1["Month"] = CURRENT_MONTH
  dataframe2["Month"] = LAST_MONTH
  df_list = [dataframe1, dataframe2]
  combinedMonthVulnDataFrame = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
  combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.Fixable = combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.Fixable.astype('bool')
  filteredVulns = combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.copy()
  uniqueVulnsNewOrChanged = filteredVulns.drop_duplicates(subset=COMPARE_SUBSET_ALL_UNIQUE, keep=False, ignore_index=True)
  logger.info(f"  uniqueVulnsNewOrChanged: {len(uniqueVulnsNewOrChanged.index)}") #correct
```

Ideally "filteredVulns" should only have the non-duplicated rows from combinedMonthVulnDataFrame but which should then be removed from combinedMonthDataFrame.  But part of the problem looks like some of the "Fixable" column have been converted from TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 in the output as well which looks to be duplicating rows which would otherwise be dropped.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem/usecase correct.
But what I did is I created two csv files from your data and loaded them into DataFrames (with only one entry changed).

For me drop_duplicates() worked just fine and also changing the datatype of Fixable made no difference/was not necessary.

Maybe my code can help you.

```
import pandas as pd

# your test data
test_a = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

# again your test data with one entry changed (1 new entry other dups)
test_b = pd.read_csv("test_b.csv")

df_list = [test_a, test_b]

# combine the two dfs
combined_test = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

# test data type
print(f"Data type before converting{type(combined_test.Fixable[0])}")
combined_test.Fixable = combined_test.Fixable.astype("bool")

# test data type again
print(f"Data type after converting{type(combined_test.Fixable[0])}")

# show df
print("Before dropping dubs")
print(combined_test)

# drop the dubs
combined_test = combined_test.drop_duplicates()
print("After dropping dubs")
print(combined_test)
```

Comment: Part of the dropping needs to ignore certain columns, we've tried with using subsets and with the code above, and it drops most but not all for some reason.  As per the Boolean, it does report the type as boolean and I've even set it with an astype, but in my output sometimes I'm still getting 0/1 instead of FALSE/TRUE, while I do still get FALSE/TRUE about 2/3 of the time.

Comment: @Robert Can you provide me with sample datasets that are concatenated and a minimal working code example that reproduces your problem? I think I dont quite understand your use case and problem.